# Извлечение SingleNode

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap

Имеется xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <InvokeMethodResponse xmlns="http://sameurl.com/gateway">
            <InvokeMethodResult>
                <DictionaryItem>
                    <Name>dbresult</Name>
                    <Value>0</Value>
                </DictionaryItem>
                <DictionaryItem>
                    <Name>result</Name>
                    <Value>300_300</Value>
                </DictionaryItem>
                <DictionaryItem>
                    <Name>customer</Name>
                    <Value>vasya</Value>
                </DictionaryItem>
                <DictionaryItem>
                    <Name>age</Name>
                    <Value>26</Value>
                </DictionaryItem>
            </InvokeMethodResult>
        </InvokeMethodResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

пытаюсь выбрать

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/InvokeMethodResponse/InvokeMethodResult/DictionaryItem[Name="dbresult"]/Value
```

но возвращается null

Код:

```
XmlDocument readData = XmlDocument ;
readData.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(readData.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
nsmgr.PushScope();                
nsmgr.AddNamespace("imr", "http://sameurl.com/gateway");                    
MessageBox.Show(readData.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Body/imr:InvokeMethodResponse/imr:InvokeMethodResult/imr:DictionaryItem[Name=\"dbresult\"]/imr:Value", nsmgr).Value);
```

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Небольшое замечание: `nsmgr.PushScope();` у вас лишний

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. При обращении к узлу `Name` тоже нужно указывать пространство имен.
2. Чтобы вытащить текст из узла, используйте `/text()`.

`/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/imr:InvokeMethodResponse/imr:InvokeMethodResult/imr:DictionaryItem[imr:Name='dbresult']/imr:Value/text()`

Comment: исправил, но всё также получаю NullReferenceException.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСмелов у вас в коде ответ загружается в result, а запрос выполняется к readData, так и должно быть?

Comment: я криво скопировал, сори. В коде в readData загружается.

Comment: после текст не поставил скобки, спасибо!

Comment: `text()` не нужен - Value можно же и у элемента взять

Comment: @PavelMayorov без текста не выбирает

Answer (score 2):

То же самое через Linq2Xml делается несколько проще:

```
var imr = XNamespace.Get("http://sameurl.com/gateway");
var xml = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
var dbresult = xml.Descendants(imr + "DictionaryItem")
   .SingleOrDefault(x => (string)x.Element(imr + "Name") == "dbresult");
MessageBox.Show((string)dbresult?.Element(imr + "Value"));
```